# Why would a package be downgraded during a do-release-upgrade?

Tags: ppa, do-release-upgrade

After going from 12.04 to 14.04 via `do-release-upgrade`, I find that I have version 0.4.7 of [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net) where I previously had version 0.4.8.  The latter is provided by a ppa (viz. the ubiquitous [webupd8](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8)), which was disabled automatically by `do-release-upgrade`.  The version in the official repositories for both Precise and Trusty is 0.4.7.  Nevertheless I would not have expected the installed package to be downgraded, and can find no documentation of such a behavior.  (It is particularly annoying, because I need to manually patch and recompile this software every time it is updated due to an apparent bug in the driver for the Fujitsu p1630's touchscreen---which, incidentally, I would like to report if I could figure out where to do it.)

Can anyone confirm or disconfirm that this is the expected behavior?

**Edited to add** the output of `apt-cache rdepends --installed Xournal`:

```
archelon@ingelrayok:~$ apt-cache rdepends --installed Xournal
xournal
Reverse Depends:
archelon@ingelrayok:~$
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache rdepends --installed Xournal` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you're mistaken about the versions of Xournal on 12.04 and 14.04. From [the package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xournal):

> - precise (12.04LTS) (gnome): GTK+ Application for note taking **[universe]**
>     0.4.6~pre20110721-1build1: amd64 armhf i386 powerpc
> - trusty (14.04LTS) (gnome): GTK+ Application for note taking **[universe]**
>     4.7-1ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el
> - wily (gnome): GTK+ Application for note taking **[universe]**
>     1:0.4.8-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el

12.04 had 0.4.6, and 14.04 had 0.4.7, and moreover, the version scheme changed, so that it's now 4.7 (and it changed yet again later, so an epoch number was added: `1:0.4.8`). The [webupd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=precise) uses the older version scheme, 0.4.8. Of course 4.7 won out over 0.4.8.

Comment: I'd say you're right.  Muon (Kubuntu's GUI package manager) reports "Installed Version: 0.4.8-1" and "Available Version: 4.8.really0.4.8-0~webupd8~trusty1".  Does this qualify as a bug that I should report somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you can ask the PPA maintainer to use 14.04's version scheme for the 12.04 package as well. Otherwise, it's not much of a bug - as you can see, enabling the PPA makes 0.4.8 the preferred version once again

Comment: It didn't though.  The Available Version I quote in my other comment *is* the one the webupd8 ppa gives for [Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=trusty), without the zero.

Comment: Didn't it? I don't know Muon, but I'd guess that the Available Version is the one that will be installed if you do an upgrade - that's apt's preferred version (I'm not sure where the installed version came from, though).

Comment: The installed version was compiled from [the 0.4.8 source](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/xournal/xournal-0.4.8.tar.gz) by me and installed with checkinstall.  (The source had to be [modified](https://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/bugs/112/?limit=10&page=1#000f) to work around a bug on my system.)  Note that it's only for Precise that the webupd8 ppa offers Xournal 0.4.8; for Trusty it gives "4.8.really0.4.8-0~webupd8~trusty1".

Comment: Yes, I did note that. The PPA maintainer uses 14.04's version scheme for their 14.04 package; they used 4.8 instead of 0.4.7, then added the `really0.4.8-0` for clarity. What of it?

Comment: Well, you had said "enabling the PPA makes 0.4.8 the preferred version once again", so I was trying to clarify that it doesn't (on Trusty), and observing explicitly that one would expect the installed 0.4.8 to update to the available 4.8.  But I forgot that this question is separate from [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/791417/192986), for which I apologize.