# Update notification for user-modified package

Tags: apt, notification, aptitude, do-release-upgrade, muon-package-manager

For a long time I had a copy of [Xournal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xournal/) 0.4.8 which I had [modified](https://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/bugs/112/?limit=10&page=1#000f); update notifications and aptitude never proposed that I "update" it to the repository version (or actually to the version in [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8), which was, and still is, the newest).  Then [I did](https://askubuntu.com/q/789527/192986) a `do-release-upgrade` from Kubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, which downgraded Xournal to version 0.4.7.  (**Edit:** Actually this is technically false; see my answer.) So after re-enabling the ppa (and updating), I replaced the stock Xournal (from the ppa) with my modified version again, and shortly thereafter a routine `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` produced

```
The following packages will be updated:
xournal
```

Of course `sudo aptitude hold xournal` prevents this unwanted "update" from occurring (although there is still always an "updates available" icon in the notification area that I don't know how to get rid of), but I would like to know the reason for this change in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually the expected behavior, since the version number of Xournal is now 4.8 instead of 0.4.8 (due to some sort of clerical error, I guess?), as pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/791424/192986).  This is also why 0.4.8 was "upgraded" to 4.7.

Preventing the unwanted "update" may be accomplished by "holding" the package, to wit:

```
sudo aptitude hold xournal
```

--at least if one uses `aptitude` for software updates, as I do.  But since the update notification icon in the system tray is generated by Muon Update Notifier, in order to eliminate that it is necessary to mark the package as held also in Muon Package Manager.  The latter would first have to be installed on a stock system, as it was removed at some point from the default installation.